# Problem in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S =\{A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}:a_{ij}\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\}$, B and C are subset of S s.t. $B=\{A\in S:|A|=1\}$ and $C=\{A\in S:|A|=-1\}$. Then for n>=2 which is true..

1)B and C are finite sets.
2)B and C are infinite sets.
3)|B|=|C| if n>=2
4)|B| not equal to |C|

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, does $|A|$ refer to the determinant of $A$ in this context?

Comment: Yes..|A|= det A, but since B, C are sets then |B|,|C| refers to number of elements in the sets B and C.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- Any subset of a finite set is finite
- Switching the first two rows of any matrix with determinant $1$ produces a matrix with determinant $-1$